Cast generic Entity data type to a CustomEarlyBoundEntity data type
I am developing a Plug-In for a Dynamics CRM environment for which I have available Early Bound Classes.
on the first lines of my code I have a variable on which is saved an object of type "Entity" and I need to cast it into a "Contact" data type, from the early bound classes. I have done so :
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
  Entity targetEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

  if (targetEntity.LogicalName != Contact.EntityLogicalName)
      return;

  Contact updatingContact = targetEntity.ToEntity<Contact>();

Problem is, object "updatingContact" is filled with null values. No values gets passed from "targetEntity" to "updatingContact".
I thought this was the right way how to cast variables into different compatible types.
Can anyone tell me what´s wrong?

I'm not entirely sure about the whole context of your plugin logic since you only posted a part of it but you can check/read Input and output parameters
as stated here
Note that not all requests contain a Target property that is of type Entity, 
so you have to look at each request or response. For example, DeleteRequest has a Target 
property, but its type is EntityReference.

You can follow the same code given on the documentation.
Another idea (which I prefer) is to execute an IOrganizationService.Retrieve command. Code somelike this (not tested):
var columns = new ColumnSet();
columns.AllColumns = true; //this line was set to retrieve all columns, feel free to modify it so it will return only what you needed.
//note: returning all fields/column has a performance impact.

Contact updatingContact = localContext.OrganizationService.Retrieve("contact", targetEntity.Id, columns);


yes. Thanks @Ikyong for your answer. I am now applying the Retrieve() method as suggested in your answer.
But apparently what I am trying to achieve is not possible.
I wanted to skip the initialization of an Entity object if possible, but I realized that there is nothing wrong in defining a general Entity object retrieving the informations from InputParameter context and then use those infos to populate an EarlyBound Contact object.
